# Why would a name containing " 'or " fail when it gets put through .serialize() in an ajax call

Tags: json, ajax, forms, serialization

I have a form that takes the users inputs (like most forms) and when a user has a name or any other string with the " 'or " (minus the spaces) it doesn't hit the controller being called by the function ***(previous poor wording) fails to validate***.

It is also only for that combination the single quotation followed by "or" any other combiniation works. For example "O'Sullivan" is fine but "D'oreily" fails.

I am wondering if I am missing something as I have no clue what to have in my google search string to find the answer to this. I am at a loss.

My guesses so far have been focused on the single quotation being escaped incorrectly but then other combinations would also be failing.

The serialize is being performed by ajax:

`data: $("form").serialize()`

All number of .replace()'s have been tried all ending up with the same result. That being happy to change "O'sullivan" unhappy to change "D'oreily" (it should be noted combinations of capitalisation and lower case yield the same results).

If you need more information please let me know but I've been stumped for half my day trying to wrap my head around what is going on. Time for other eyes to look at it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would be surprised if `serialize` would be the culprit. It sounds more like you have a WAF (web application firewall) which thinks the `'or` looks like an SQL injection attempt and blocks it. What does "fails to validate" mean exactly?

Comment: @CherryDT good point, I edited the question with better wording in that area. As for the WAF it does hit this : 
```
IList<String> BlackList = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>
            (new List<String> {
                //@"(;|\s)(exec|execute|select|insert|update|delete|create|alter|drop|rename|truncate|backup|restore)\s",
                @"(\-\-)",
                @"((\%3D)|(=))[^\n]*((\%27)|(\')|(\-\-)|(\%3B)|(;))",
                @"\w*((\%27)|(\'))((\%6F)|o|(\%4F))((\%72)|r|(\%52))",
                @"exec(\s|\+)+(s|x)p\w+",
                @"((\%3C)|<)[^\n]+((\%3E)|>)" ```

Comment: What is the response of the AJAX request in devtools? And do you have any WAF? Maybe your hosting provider uses one and you don't even know?

Comment: Apologies for the trash formatting. I am new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Just saw your edit. OK then you know the issue - this blacklist is what's stopping it from working. You have `'or` in your blacklist. (this is why such blacklists or firewalls are only a stopgap measure - they can't protect from everything but instead they cause false positives. The best way is to write robust code in the first place that doesn't have any SQL injection attack vectors.)